# Matplotlib Scatter plot with lat and long on the X Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, geography, scatter

I am generating scattle plots with three dimensions of data for ocenographyc profiles. The Y axis is depth, X axis is time, and Z (colour) is the parameter (temperature, chlorophyll ..) . My problem is I want to change now the X axis from the datetime, to the latitude and longitude. It is pretty easy to use just one of the variables, because they are numbers, but I don't know how to use the pair.

The first thing I thought was to use strings, but the density of data I have is too big, so if I do that matplotlib can't compress the axis as with numbers and it is impossible to see anything.

My second attemp was to use twiny:

```
ax.set_xlabel("Coords")
ax2 = ax.twiny()           
labels = a2x.get_xticks().tolist()
```

And then try to assign manually the pair of latitude and longitude tho the adjusted labels. The problem here is the values I obtain form labels are interpolated latitudes, not the real ones, so I don't know how to assign the proper longitude.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: How do you transform data on a plane (2-d lat/lon coordinates) to a line (x-axis)? You need to *look* at the plane from its edge.  Which is more important, that lat or lon?  Use that one for the x-axis.  Or make two side-by-side plots one with lat and one with lon on the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you wwii. The couple is the important thing, basically we need that to be able to follow biological structures under water.

Comment: From what I understand, your x-coordinate is really the distance traversed by something. You should be able to compute this. Then plot against this and adjust tick locations and label according to your requirements.

Comment: Yes, you are right that the x axis can be distance. The distance covered by an underwater glider. But if using distance is the same than using time, it is not going to give the scientist a fast way of knowing where the robot was. Of course it is not that difficult to correlate those values with position, but it seems it is what the y want. I actually think it would be really interesting to find out if it is doable.

Comment: Sounds like you actually have 4-d data.  lat, lon for the y and x axes. Depth for the z-axis.  Some type of color scheme for the data point.